# Navigate from a ListBox to a Detail Page. WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8, exception, listbox, navigation, master-detail

By following the guide at http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/windows-phone-mvvm-master---details-navigation-in-5-minutes I added a new project to my solution in order to display a MasterPage (containing a ListBox with an image and a texblock in the DataTemplate)  and a DetailsPage (Header, Image and TextBlock within a StackPanel). The list shows just fine, but at tapping either on the image or the textblock does not navigate to the DetailsPage or anywhere else, but it throws this error in the output:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   Microsoft.Phone.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native
>   boundary The program '[732] TaskHost.exe' has exited with code -1
>   (0xffffffff).

And goes to this portion of code in the App cs file:

```C#
// Code to execute if a navigation fails
private void RootFrame_NavigationFailed(object sender, NavigationFailedEventArgs e)
{
    if (Debugger.IsAttached)
    {
        // A navigation has failed; break into the debugger
            Debugger.Break();
    }
}
```

If I hold the cursor the the 'e' parameter in NavigationFailed procedure, it says:

> No XAML was found at the location ‘/DetailsPage.xaml’

This is what I have in the 'MasterPage.xaml' wich contains the list:

```XAML
<StackPanel x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <TextBlock Text="Tips Semana 1" Style="{StaticResource WeekHeader}"/>

    <ListBox x:Name="MainListBox" Margin="10" Background="#50F5F5F5" Foreground="Black"
             ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
             SelectionChanged="MainListBox_SelectionChanged" >

        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Width="100" Height="100" Stretch="Uniform"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="10" 
                               FontSize="25" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</StackPanel>
```

And here's the code behind. Please if anyone could tell me the error and guide me correctly in the usage of SelectedItem / selectedItem / SelectedIndex / selectedIndex (I just don't know how to use them, nor their correct notation)

```C#
private void MainListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //If Selected Item is null (no selection) do nothing
    if (MainListBox.SelectedItem == null)

        return;

    //Navigate to the new page
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/DetailsPage.xaml?selectedItem=" + MainListBox.SelectedItem, UriKind.Relative));

    //NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/DetailsPage.xaml?selectedIndex=" + MainListBox.SelectedIndex, UriKind.Relative));

    //Reset selected item to null (no selection)
    MainListBox.SelectedItem = null;
}
```

Comment: Does your Solution Explorer look like this: http://i.imgur.com/EI62RqS.png   ?

Comment: Yes, it looks the same plus an 'images' folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, change your code back to `SelectedIndex` however I would use some other number to identify your custom classes.

This exception your are getting means in most cases that it cannot find requested page in your solution. If you moved DetailsPage to some subfolder, you need to change the path to something like this: [Subfolder]/DetailsPage.xaml...

Also, if you get exception again, hover over `e` argument in `private void RootFrame_NavigationFailed(object sender, NavigationFailedEventArgs e)` and tell us what it says.

Answer (score 0):

Got it!
You were kind of right Parad1s3.
As I added a new project to my solution, the navigation service requires the full path of the second project and page to navigate to (curious I think since I am navigating between pages already in the second project).
Well, here is my Solution:

In MasterPage:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/DataBoundApp1;component/DetailsPage.xaml?selectedItem=" + (MainLongListSelector.SelectedItem as ItemViewModel).ID, UriKind.Relative));
```

Thank you for helping!

Comment: Glad it works! You should've mention, that your solution has more projects ;) Navigation is then slightly different as you solutions shows.